# How to check rows same type of data using selenium

Tags: selenium

Scenario is after clicking on spin button, if any row has same types of shapes then 500 points should be print in Score box, if any row have same type of 2 shapes and one shape is different than 300 points should be print in Score box,if any row three different shapes then 100 points should print in Score Box.

Document attached,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned any `html` or any content . I have some solution which may helps you

1. Suppose your all 9 images are presenting in a table and the `<td>` tag changes the class name to correspondent image after spin e.g if `td` image changes to square image then class added to that td  like - `<td class="square">`
2. Identify the uniqueness what happening in your html and change the code as per that it is simple logical example -

   ```
   List<WebElement> allelement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='mytable']//td"));

   int count=0;
   for(int i=0;i<allelement.size();i++)
   {
       switch(i)
       {
       case 0:
       case 3:
       case 6:
           if(allelement.get(i).getAttribute("class").equals(allelement.get(i+1).getAttribute("class")))
           {
               if(allelement.get(i).getAttribute("class").equals(allelement.get(i+2).getAttribute("class")))
               {
                   System.out.println("Spin 500");
               }
               else
               {
                   System.out.println("Spin 300");
               }
            }
           else if(allelement.get(i+1).getAttribute("class").equals(allelement.get(i+2).getAttribute("class")))
           {
               System.out.println("Spin 300");
           }
           else
           {
               count++;
               if(count==3)
               {
                   System.out.println("Spin 100");
               }
           }
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: @karthikashoka, is it helpful for you ?